# Chrome Dev Tools. I am trying exclude extension js files from step by step debugging. But "Blackbox content script" in settings doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When using the Sources panel of Chrome DevTools to step through code, sometimes you pause on code from Chrome Extensions.

There is a solution from documentation: [Blackbox Chrome Extension Scripts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/guides/blackbox-chrome-extension-scripts)

But even if I enable this parameter:
[image]

The code debugger still is pausing in content sctipts (chome extenstion js files)
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: It is a [known issue before](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/hhNPDusBjHA), you can try to follow up on the [filed bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341082).

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a pattern.

You can do it simply clicking the right button on the code of the script you want to black and selecting "Black box script".

[image]

Let me know if it works.